# Syncing Windows 2012 time to Windows 7

Tags: windows, time-synchronization

I have one Windows 2012 server and one Windows 7 computer, none of them are running Active Directory.
I want the Windows 2012 server to sync its clock with the Windows 7 computer (the Windows 7 computer has correct clock, the Windows 2012 computer has wrong clock).

Comment: Windows 7 by default is set to sync with time.windows.com so you can probabaly do the same thing on the server. Make sure Windows Time service is enabled and sync to Microsoft time.

Comment: I have no internet on the computers..

Comment: I think this may have been answered here http://superuser.com/questions/375457/how-to-synchronize-clocks-for-computers-that-are-not-online

Answer (score 2):

Some bad advice is given in the Superuser answer linked in the comments. There is absolutely no reason to setup a domain to only get time sync working. It would be pointless to setup a virtual environment to run a NTP server.

Windows Time Service is automatically working in domain mode and in those cases you should be very carefully when playing around as it has special algorithms to choose the best time source.

When not in a domain the Windows Time Service is using NTP to set time against `time.windows.com`.

You can change that with the command:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:pool.ntp.org /syncfromflags:MANUAL
```

Change `pool.ntp.org` to your local IP address of your  NTP server.

The Windows Time Service can furthermore act as a NTP server. This is done by a setting in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpServer
```

Change `Enabled` from `0` to `1` and restart the service (or server).

Be sure to open for incoming UDP on port `123` on your NTP server (and other firewalls inbetween).

Windows Time Service have an accuracy of 1 - 2 seconds. If you need to be more precise than this then you should use a [third party service](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp.htm#ntp_stable).